# Why is Plot better than NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to minimize the LogisticSigmoid[50+a] function, which is defined as

$$ \frac{1}{1+e^{-50-a}}$$

so if i write

```
NMinimize[1/(1 + E^(-50 - a)), a]
```

> {1., {a -> -6.96782}}

which is clearly wrong. But if i just write the function in the notebook and click on the suggestionbar on "plot" mathmatica chooses this plot range:

```
Plot[1/(1 + E^(-50 - a)), {a, -62., -38.}]
```

which gives

[image]

**So why is plot apparently better in guessing the relevant range of the function, when NMinmize cannot do it?**

Or put in another way: The NMinmize function could be improved if it also plots the function and then picks the lowest pixel in the graph as minimum if this minimum is below the calculated one.

Comment: From help it says, under possible issues
`For nonlinear functions, NMinimize may sometimes find only a local
minimum`

Comment: You can use `FindMinimum[1/(1 + E^(-50 - a)), {a, -50}]` with an initial guess, which gives `{4.48816*10^-252,{a->-628.75}}`.

Comment: Yes i know. I can also give NMinimise a starting point, but that is not really my question.

Comment: What output are you expecting? The `LogisticSigmoid` function has no minimum. It goes to 0 asymptotically at negative infinity, but that's not a real minimum. `Minimize[1/(1 + E^(-50 - a)), a]` tells you as much.

Comment: Why does NMinmize gives the (asymptotically) maximal value, when "plot" has no problem in finding the correct (asymptotical) solution.

Comment: `Plot` does not find anything. It only plots the function on the domain you specify. It's the suggestions bar you clicked on that located the transition region. Now as to the question why the suggestion bar manages to do that while `NMinimize` doesn't: I don't know. Still, it's an ill-posed question, so it's not that surprising the output is strange.

Comment: Note, that there are precision issues here as well, which you can see by adding the option `WorkingPrecision -> 50`. Using another method also helps, here `Method -> "NelderMead"` will come closer to the "truth".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Comment: `NMinimize`and the suggestion bar of `Plot` have different objectives. `Plot` is not minimising, the goal is to show interesting range where function is not constant. To achieve this goal the analytic form is probably analysed. `NMinimize` does not use this information.

Answer (score 5):

> So why is plot apparently better in guessing the relevant range of the function, when NMinmize cannot do it?

It isn't.  You told `Plot` what range to consider: `{-60, -38}`.  If you also tell `NMinimize`, it will give a sensible result.

```
NMinimize[{1/(1 + E^(-50 - a)), -60 < a < -38}, a]
(* {0.0000453979, {a -> -60.}} *)
```

There are multiple issues with this function:

- It has no minimum (it gets arbitrarily close to zero without reaching it).
- It has almost completely flat plateaus. A numerical optimization algorithm that looks only locally cannot tell that this function isn't constant.

Comment: > You told Plot what range to consider: {-60, -38}. No! I did not. That is the point.

Comment: Right, the `Plot` suggestion also figured out the range of interest. As for the original issue, My guess is `NMaximize in the absence of a viable initial guess simply stalled out trying to crawl away from an approximate maximum.

Comment: @kiara I thought I added a comment on this, but I seem to have failed to press Enter.  Here's what I wrote: "I missed the suggestions bar comment. Even if the `Plot` command was generated by the suggestion bar, the point is that the range was passed to `Plot`. It was not determined by `Plot`."

Comment: @kiara The suggestions bar is meant to guide you, the user. It merely tries to give you a reasonable starting point that you will tweak to your needs. Sometimes its guesses are good, at other times they're awful.  I do not think it is meant to produce values to use in an optimization algorithm, even if in this specific case its suggestions would have worked.